# How to use https and socks4 proxies

Tags: go, proxy

I couldn't find a way to do this in golang, so I'm asking.

I have various proxies (http://~,https://~ etc)

Requests will be accepted for http://ip:port and socks5://ip:port, but not for https://ip:port and sock4://ip:port.

What should I do?

Is the only way to assign it to an environment variable?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "net/url"
)

func main(){
    req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", site URL, nil)
    req.Close = true

    var proxy string = "proxy"
    a, _ := url.Parse(proxy)
    i := &http.Transport{
        Proxy: http.ProxyURL(a),
        TLSClientConfig: &tls.Config{InsecureSkipVerify: true},
    }
    client := &http.Client{
        Transport: i,
    }
    resp, _ := client.Do(req)
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    doc, _ := goquery.NewDocumentFromReader(resp.Body)
    fmt.Println(doc)
}
```

Comment: are you getting "Bad request" error?

Comment: Yes.
client.Do returns "Bad request" error?

Answer (score 1):

The following code works fine at my end

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "net/url"
)

func main(){
    req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", site URL, nil)
    req.Close = true

    var proxy string = "proxy"
    a, _ := url.Parse(proxy)
    i := &http.Transport{
    Proxy: http.ProxyURL(a),
    //Proxy: http.ProxyFromEnvironment,
    TLSClientConfig: &tls.Config{InsecureSkipVerify: true},
    TLSNextProto:    make(map[string]func(authority string, c *tls.Conn) http.RoundTripper),

    }

    client := &http.Client{}
    client.Transport = i
    resp, err := client.Do(req)

if err != nil {
    log.Fatalln(err)
    return
}
defer resp.Body.Close()

    doc, _ := goquery.NewDocumentFromReader(resp.Body)
    fmt.Println(doc)
}
```

I hope it helps you in same

Comment: Thank you
I've seen this in the answers to other questions, but is sock4 going to be this way as well?
disable https? I thought it was a thing.
Requests for sock4 have not passed yet.

Comment: Thanks. It worked for me. I was not using `TLSNextProto` .  What is the use of that? Things are not working without defining that.